# Выезжающий блок по клику на кнопку

Tags: javascript, jquery

нужна помощь, как сделать по клику на кнопку выезжающий блок с текстовой информацией, но блок должен появляться под определенным блоком?

Comment: @Kvilios Вот что получилось на данный момент https://jsfiddle.net/0qr6ksjx/1/, но я не понимаю, как сделать, чтобы блок появлялся под определенным блоком

Comment: @BitBoy, поясните, что Вы подразумеваете под "*определенным блоком*"? У Вас в [примере](https://jsfiddle.net/0qr6ksjx/1/) блок и так появляется под блоком (`<div>` под `<a>`).

Comment: @Kvilios под блоком, который имеет определенный id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариантов множество, JS, JQ, CSS..
В следующий раз задавайте вопрос как можно точнее, как и что, и желательно с примером, гадалок тут нет.

Вот пример реализации "механики" на JQ, дальше сами додумаете, или уточните - я подправлю.

```js
$('.open-modal, .close-modal').on('click', function(){
  $('.modal').toggle();
});
```

```css
.open-modal, .close-modal {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.open-modal {
  color: green;
}

.close-modal {
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ddd;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="open-modal">Показать блок</div>
<div class="modal">
  <div>Тут текст</div>
  <div class="close-modal">Закрыть</div>
</div>
```

---

Под определённым блоком?
Типо спойлера?

Что-то типо такого?

```js
$('.item[data-for]').on('click', function(){
  let data = $(this).data('for'); // Определяем data
  let item = $(data+'.hide-block'); // Ищем блок
  
  if(item.length>0) { // Существует ли такой блок на странице
    item.toggle(); // показываем\прячем
  }
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: block;
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.text {
  background: gray;
}

.hide-block {
  display: none;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item" data-for="#id1">Открыть блок под текстом</div>

<div class="text">Какой-то текст где много букв.</div>
<div id="id1" class="hide-block">Нужный блок</div>
<div class="text">Какой-то текст где много букв.</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как сделать, чтобы именно под определнным блоком выезжал этот скрытый блок? Ну т.е у блока допустим есть id, и именно под этим id выезжает скрытый блок

Comment: @BitBoy, дополнил ответ

Comment: Не совсем, под определнным, это значит, что у меня есть на странице блок c id допустим id1, и именно под этим id1 должен появится скрытый блок

Comment: Сможете переделать?

Comment: Проще этому блоку выставить какой-нибудь идентификатор и открывать его.