# Сделать блок выезжающим

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрытый блок, который отображается по клику по кнопке, как сделать, чтобы он выезжал сверху, а не просто появлялся? И подскажите, как добавить в блоке крестик для закрытия данного блока.

```js
$('.item[data-for]').on('click', function() {
  let data = $(this).data('for'); // Определяем data
  let item = $(data + '.hide-block'); // Ищем блок

  if (item.length > 0) { // Существует ли такой блок на странице
    item.toggle(); // показываем\прячем
  }
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: block;
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 750px;
}

.text {
  background: gray;
}

.hide-block {
  display: none;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 815px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  width: 70%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" data-for="#id1">AirDrop</div>
<div id="id1" class="hide-block">
  <p style="text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: black;">Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выезжающий блок по клику на кнопку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/947229/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83)

Comment: Может, вы все же начнете прислушиваться к комментариям?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko а что не так? это другой вопрос

Comment: Вы скопировали код с предыдущего ответа, ничем его не дополнили. Вы не стремитесь разобраться, научиться.

Answer (score 0):

Замени `.toggle()` на [.slideToggle()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

```js
$('.item[data-for], .close[data-for]').on('click', function() {
  let data = $(this).data('for'); // Определяем data
  let item = $(data + '.hide-block'); // Ищем блок

  if (item.length > 0) { // Существует ли такой блок на странице
    item.slideToggle(); // показываем\прячем
  }
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: block;
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 750px;
}

.text {
  background: gray;
}

.hide-block {
  display: none;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 815px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  width: 70%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" data-for="#id1">AirDrop</div>
<div id="id1" class="hide-block">
  <p style="text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: black;">Text</p>
        <div class="close" data-for="#id1">X</div>
</div>
```